# Cannot add a background color to html element outside of App.Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

first of all, thank you for reading my question!

I am looking to add a background color, a gradient more specifically, to a Vue page. Not all pages, but just one. But when I write this in components/Frontpage.Vue

```
html {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #17ead9, #6078ea);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

it doesn't work, the background stays white. But when I put the exact same code in App.Vue, it works perfectly. I can work around that issue by importing an external css. But it doesn't look really clean. Does someone have a solution?

EDIT: So basically: I have to put my background in  because it can only be displayed on this page. But because it is scoped, I can't access the 'html'-element.

Thank you very much for having read my question, even if you cannot help me. It's my first post on StackOverflow!

Comment: Seems to work largely as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/cojz0rj1/

Comment: Yes, but in vue.js, the code from components/Frontpage.Vue runs inside App.Vue. I can access the html tag from App.Vue, but not from components/Frontpage.Vue.

Comment: Oh, so it's a specificity problem? In that case, if you can't change the original code, you may have to resort to tricks like `!important`.

Comment: I tried it, but I cannot acces the element. I can't add any css to the html element. But I guess the solution would be a specific Vue.js trick

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because you have scoped attribute in the style tag:

```
<style scoped>
html {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #17ead9, #6078ea);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
```

> https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html
>
> When a  tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only.

Remove the scoped attribute to make your css work, or you can add multiple style tags if you don't want every css to be unscoped

```
<style>
html {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #17ead9, #6078ea);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

---

### edit1

To make `<html>` use different style when change page,

#### 1. toogle class in vue-router's afterEach hook

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  if (to.name === "page2") {
    document.querySelector("html").classList.add("page2");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("page2");
  }
});
```

#### 2. add html.page2 style

```
<style>
html.page2 {
  background-color: gray;
}
</style>
```

#### 3. Example:

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Fantastic! I indeed use <style scoped>. That way I keep the css specific to that component. It's the only page where the background isn't white. But your solution and a <style>background: white</style> in App.Vue will do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well..., it didn't work. I put the background color without a scope limitation, so it works on the html-element. But even tho I rectify the background as white on other pages, the background stays blue. It only becomes whit again when I refresh the page.

Comment: So basically: I have to put my background in because it can only be displayed on this page. But because it is scoped, I can't access the 'html'-element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Vue lifecycle methods to add or remove classes.

```
created() {
 document.querySelector("html").classList.add("someClass");
},
destroyed() {
  document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("someClass");
}
```

Then make sure to have that css class in a separate style block outside of your scoped block.

```
<style>
 .someClass {
   background: red;
 }
</style>

<style scoped>
  ... rest of your css 
</style>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So, Thank you for all who helped, but I found a workaround.

In the App.vue I put this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

That way I don't have to access the html to edit the full page background. The highest element there is in components/frontpage.vue (which is one big ) is now itself full page, so now I can put my background on this element in a  tag.

```
#Frontpage {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #17ead9, #6078ea);
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Now my page has a full screen blue background that immediately disappears when I go on another page. Without having to refresh it.